# Generate a 5 digit number, but with exception from a MySQL table column

Tags: mysql, exception, numbers

I have a MySQL database who contains a table named `images`. In that table I have a column named `file_name`. The `file_name` column contains 5 rows:

```
.---.-----------.
| # | file_name |
.---.-----------.
| 1 | 00000     |
| 2 | 00001     |
| 3 | 00002     |
| 4 | 00003     |
| 5 | 00004     |
.---------------.
```

My query code is:

```
<?php
require_once('config/config_db.php');
$SQLquery = "SELECT `file_name` FROM images";
$result = mysql_query($SQLquery);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['file_name']."<br>"; // ?
}
?>
```

I have the following PHP function who generates a 5 digit random function, but my exeptions are introduced manually in `$exception` variable array (as you can see below). My goal is to get from `file_name` column all rows, and set in `$exception` variable. I tried to achieve this 3 or 4 hours, but no success. Thank you for your time.

The PHP function:

```
<?php
function getRandom($exception=array('00000', '00001', '00002', '00003', '00004')){ // ?
    $rand = str_pad(mt_rand(0,99999),5,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if(in_array($rand,$exception))return getRandom($exception);
    return $rand;
}

echo getRandom().'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: 1) Stop using `mysql_` functions. 2) Fetch and store your db id's in an array, pass the array to your function, then use something like `array_diff()`.

Comment: Taking a step back, are you trying to return a 5 digit number which hasn't previously been used?

Comment: I am try to generate a number wich hasn't previously been used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my earlier question, this might do the job for you in a single SQL statement:-

```
SELECT aNumber
FROM (
SELECT LPAD(CONVERT(a.i+b.i*10+c.i*100+d.i*1000+e.i*10000,CHAR(5)),5,'0') AS aNumber
FROM integers a, integers b, integers c, integers d, integers e) Sub1
LEFT OUTER JOIN images b ON Sub1.aNumber = b.file_name
WHERE b.file_name IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Uses a table called integers with a single column called i and 10 rows with the values 0 to 9.

It is using *ORDER BY RAND()* which is a bit slow so probably worth you optimising that a bit.